# Filter newest x % per group in timeseries and compute aggregates

Tags: python, pandas

What's the best way to filter a timeseries per group, taking x % of most recent measurements and then compute multiple aggregates over the entire filtered dataset?
I'm currently using the following code, but is this correct or is there a better way to achieve this goal?

```
fraction = 0.7

def df_by_ts_head_fraction(df):
    end_idx = math.ceil(len(df) * fraction)
    return df.sort_values(by='timestamp', ascending=False).iloc[:end_idx]

data = [[datetime.fromisoformat('2020-08-28 08:00'), 55.66, 'a']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['timestamp', 'measurement', 'group'])

df = df.groupby('group').\
    apply(df_by_ts_head_fraction).\
    aggregate(['mean', 'median', 'size'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to achieve the stated goal

```
df = df.groupby('timestamp').\
    apply(df_by_ts_head_fraction).\
    reset_index(drop=True).\
    loc[:, ['timestamp', 'measurement']].\
    groupby('timestamp').\
    aggregate(['mean', 'median', 'size'])
```